# Passing in Google Service Account Details Inline with Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I'm currently using the Google Cloud Client Library for Java for authorization for Google APIs.

I'm currently doing the authorization as follows:

```
GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(JSON_FILE))
      .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
```

Is there any way to inline the details in the JSON_FILE within Java? That way I don't need direct access to the actual JSON file?

I notice that you can do it via the Node.js SDK (shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) but I can't seem to find an example with java. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following [doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage) useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation provided at the [Google Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2) yo have to pass the json file as a parameter in order to get the access to the application data and also this can be confirmed if you take a look at the [GoogleCredentials class](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/master/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.java) (you can notice that the Json file is required)

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods that I can think of.

1. Put your Json credentials into a string. Call `fromStream(myStream)` to process a string or memory stream from your json string.
2. Bypass the GoogleCredentials class and create your own Signed JWT and pass the access token to `create(accessToken)`.

[GoogleCredentials.java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/master/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.java)

Note. I would not recommend your idea of storing the service account credentials in the source code. This is not recommended from a security posture.